# Two derivations commuting with the exterior derivation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Why is the following statement true:

> "Two derivations are equal if they agree on $0$ forms $f$ and exact $1$-forms $df$ since locally they generate the exterior algebra." ?

I found this statement in [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39540/is-cartans-magic-formula-due-to-%C3%89lie-or-henri) post.